# how to get rss feed in an android app page from a live website?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I have an ASP.NET website and I want to develop simple android application with 1 page in which I want to get live data from RSS FEED of my website.

The link of my website rss feed is like: http://www.mydomain.com/latestnewsrss.aspx?languageid=7

In the android application I just want to display all the news coming from RSS FEED of website in a list.

I am following this tutorial but it is not running (I don't know why): http://nscraps.com/Java/523-rss-feed-reader-example-java.htm

when I try to run the my code on phone, I get error saying "force app to stop/close"

------------log cat-------------

```
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 2
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/Zygote(33): setreuid() failed. errno: 17
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/BatteryService(55): usbOnlinePath not found
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/BatteryService(55): batteryVoltagePath not found
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/BatteryService(55): batteryTemperaturePath not found
07-18 19:24:27.657: ERROR/SurfaceFlinger(55): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake
07-18 19:24:46.946: ERROR/EventHub(55): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
07-18 19:24:46.946: ERROR/EventHub(55): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55): Failure starting core service
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55): java.lang.SecurityException
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55):     at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55):     at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)
07-18 19:24:47.268: ERROR/System(55):     at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:184)
07-18 19:24:49.516: ERROR/SoundPool(55): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
07-18 19:24:49.546: ERROR/SoundPool(55): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
07-18 19:24:49.556: ERROR/SoundPool(55): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
07-18 19:24:49.566: ERROR/SoundPool(55): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
07-18 19:24:49.566: ERROR/SoundPool(55): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
07-18 19:24:52.717: ERROR/ThrottleService(55): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf
07-18 19:24:54.207: ERROR/logwrapper(143): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-18 19:24:54.257: ERROR/logwrapper(145): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-18 19:24:54.378: ERROR/logwrapper(146): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory
07-18 19:25:15.453: ERROR/HierarchicalStateMachine(55): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage: msg.what=3
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55): ANR in com.android.quicksearchbox
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55): Reason: Broadcast of Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED cmp=com.android.quicksearchbox/.SearchWidgetProvider }
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55): Load: 4.92 / 1.38 / 0.47
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55): CPU usage from 16126ms to 203ms ago:
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   ndroid.launcher: 38% = 23% user + 14% kernel / faults: 5232 minor 63 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   system_server: 23% = 10% user + 13% kernel / faults: 2891 minor 75 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   m.android.email: 17% = 8% user + 9% kernel / faults: 4012 minor 14 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   d.process.media: 17% = 9% user + 7% kernel / faults: 4273 minor 7 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   com.android.mms: 15% = 7% user + 7% kernel / faults: 3952 minor 9 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   m.android.phone: 3% = 2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 857 minor 7 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   adbd: 3% = 0% user + 3% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   d.process.acore: 3% = 2% user + 1% kernel / faults: 1710 minor 48 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   id.defcontainer: 1% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 563 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   kswapd0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   zygote: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 159 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   roid.alarmclock: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 175 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   ronsoft.openwnn: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 174 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   mmcqd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   mediaserver: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 37 minor 2 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   init: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   pdflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   rild: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 55 minor 2 major
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   qemud: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 13 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   logcat: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 53 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):   ndroid.settings: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 113 minor
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +android.protips: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +.quicksearchbox: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +loop0: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +kdmflush: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +kcryptd_io: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +kcryptd: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55):  +newfs_msdos: 0% = 0% user + 0% kernel
07-18 19:25:36.650: ERROR/ActivityManager(55): TOTAL: 100% = 50% user + 48% kernel + 0% iowait + 0% irq + 0% softirq
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.RssFeed/com.RssFeed.RssFeed}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
07-18 19:25:55.430: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(305):     ... 11 more
```

Need Help

Comment: please elaborate what problem are you facing ?

Comment: when I try to run the my code on phone, I get error saying "force app to stop/close". I will deeply appreciate if you can take a look at code and see what is the problem. thank u

Comment: You'll need t give us a little more info.  There could be many different reasons for a force close.  The best thing you can do is hook it up to a debugger like DDMS and look at the log cat output.  That will give you a place to start. If you can't figure out the error on the log cat then post it and the snippet of code that is causing the error.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I just added log cat code above, please see

Answer (score 2):

I see that an `IllegalAccessException: access to constructor not allowed` exception is thrown. Do you provide your own constructor to your activity? For example, do you have something like this:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {


    YourActivity() {

    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }

}
```

If so, bear in mind that this is not the way activities work. You should not provide a constructor for the activity. Instead, do all your initialisations in the `onCreate()` method.

Another problem could be that you want to instantiate your activity like `YourActivity activity = new YourActivity();`. This is also wrong.

Please take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) for better understanding the Activity lifecycle.